# Exception xml+php

Tags: php, xml

well guys this code trow this exception and I dont know why...

> exception: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message
>   'Not Found Error' in
>   C:\AppServ\www\CpVela\publicidades\delete_pub.php:14 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\AppServ\www\CpVela\publicidades\delete_pub.php(14):
>   DOMNode->removeChild(Object(DOMElement)) #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\AppServ\www\CpVela\publicidades\delete_pub.php on line 14

```
    <?php
   include "../src/defines.php";
if(!empty($_GET['CDG'])){
    $doc = new DOMDocument; 
    $doc->load(DIR_PUBLICIDADES);
    $thedocument = $doc->documentElement;
    $list = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('item');
    echo $list->length;
    $nodeToRemove = NULL;
    foreach ($list as $domElement){
      $attrValue = $domElement->getAttribute('numero');
      if ($attrValue == $_GET['CDG']) {
        $nodeToRemove = $domElement; 
        $thedocument->removeChild($nodeToRemove); // <<< line 14
        $f = fopen(DIR_PUBLICIDADES,'w+'); 
        fwrite($f,$doc->saveXML()); 
        fclose($f); 
      }
    }
    if ($nodeToRemove != null){

        $thedocument->removeChild($nodeToRemove);
        $f = fopen(DIR_PUBLICIDADES,'w+'); 
        fwrite($f,$doc->saveXML()); 
        fclose($f); 
    }
}
    header("location:publicidades.php"); 


    ?>
```

my code XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<publicidades>
    <internas>
        <item nombre="Tony Roma's" numero="SOL_17"   posX="266" posY="229" telefono="" web="" correo="" encargado="" descripcion=""  promocion="" ></item>
    </internas>
    <externas>

    </externas>
</publicidades>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your removeChild method.
This error is a result of:

> Raised if oldnode is not a child of this node.

`$nodeToRemove` reffers to `<item`,
while `$thedocument` reffers to the  root element node which is `<publicidades>`.

`<item>` is a child of `<internas>` not of `<public...>`.

**EDIT:**
Try adding:

```
$internas = $doc->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('internas');
```

right after:

```
$thedocument = $doc->documentElement;
```

and then:(**EDIT2**)

```
foreach ($internas as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

Comment: but how is possible??? if $thedocument is $doc->documentElement :S $doc->documentElemnt isn't child of $doc???

Comment: `echo` the values of the `current element` in the loop please.

Comment: echo $attrValue; // result = SOL_17

Comment: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::removeChild()  it's that said when I tried ur answer :S $internas call to undefined method DOMNodeList

Comment: Got It!  the `getElementsByTagName` function returns a DOMNodeList but following your XML code there's only one node match. Edited the answer once again (`EDIT2`)

Comment: hmmm but that delete all node (internas) :S